# Python Logging - Always write to log (independent of log level)

Tags: python, logging

I do the logging like following code:

```
    # Start Logging
    #
    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'pool_control.log',
                        level = logging.DEBUG,
                        filemode = 'a',
                        format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    logging.info("Logging Level: "+logging.getLevelName(logging.root.level))
    logging.info("Start of the Pool Control Application")
```

My question: How do I write a logging message into the log, independent of the log level?
I am looking for something like this:

```
logging.always_write("Start of Pool Control Application")
```

The idea behind this is, that I want later to reduce the logging level.
But I want to have this "Start of ..." always in the log. And I do not want to markt it as Error or Critical.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can create your custom logger object. At the beginning, set the debug level to INFO and print the message. After that, set the debug level to the level that you need (i.e., read from configuration file or environment).

Comment: The stdlib logging doesn't really support logging without a level. You could maybe create a custom log level that is even higher than critical but has a less severe name?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my project to work with Multiprocessing.
So I had to wrote my own Multiprocessor Logging Class.

And in this class, I can do it now by hand -> change the logging level
(so that the startup messages and end messages are always beeing written to the log file)